# Class 'MongoClient' not found, while php connecting to mongodb in ubuntu

Tags: php, mongodb

I installed mongodb version 3.0.7 in xampp, and installed php driver also. below is the php code to connect mongodb.

```
   <?php
   // connect
   $m = new MongoClient();
   // select a database
   $db = $m->test;
   ?>
```

While I run this code in my localhost I am getting this error

> **Fatal error:** Class 'MongoClient' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mongo.php **on line 3**

Comment: Have you included required classes in your app?

Comment: have you restarted your webserver for the changes to take effect ?

Comment: @Calimero: yeah, i restarted my web server.

Comment: @vitozev: No, I think no need to include any Class or file in this php file, right?

Comment: MongoClient as in http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php : "Warning: This extension that defines this class is deprecated" ?

Comment: @VolkerK: Is there any other way to connect mongodb in php ? As i know php script uses class  MongoClient()

Comment: Yes, there is/are. There's a link to an actively developed/maintained extension following the warnig message at http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php

Comment: @VolkerK: Sorry, i didn't get you. Can you explain me more in detail!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <?php
    // connect
   $m = new MongoClient();
    // select a database
    $db = $m->test;
    ?>

   This above code working fine, In xampp server you must include "extension=mongo.so" in php.ini file at usr/lib/php5/20121212/php.ini with same extension. After all setting restart your server.
```